# Is it necessary to use Hibernate to implement PrimeFaces lazy datamodel or can i just use jdbc without any ORM framework

Tags: primefaces

I have an application using connection to database pure jdbc and i need to implement lazy loads on my datatables as a performance requirement. Do i need to use an ORM as Hibernate to get this level of performance or can i achieve this behavior only using jdbc? Is there any impact to consider between this tecnologies, I'm open to comments.

Comment: No, it is not. You can use whatever you want. I have implemented it with MyBatis, Hibernate and also jdbc. The performance will depends on what you use (like cache frameworks for once).

Comment: Check the PrimeFaces showcase. What do they use there?

Comment: You can even have a web application with primefaces that doesn't connect to the database at all, but instead uses webservices exposed from another application which can connect to the database in whatever manner.